# How to connect my G-Suite in nodejs server using Gmail API

Tags: node.js, google-api, gmail-api, service-accounts, google-api-nodejs-client

I want to get access to my G-Suite account in a nodejs server, using Gmail API.
I understood I should create Service Account and authenticate with its credentials.
I tried many examples and ways but couldn't make it works.

This is the last try I've made.
returns 400 bad request.

code: 400,
errors: [
{
domain: 'global',
reason: 'failedPrecondition',
message: 'Bad Request'
}
]

```js
const {GoogleAuth} = require('google-auth-library');
const credentials = require('./sevice-account-credentials.json');

async function main() {
    const clientEmail = credentials.client_email;
    const privateKey = credentials.private_key;
    if (!clientEmail || !privateKey) {
        throw new Error(`
      The CLIENT_EMAIL and PRIVATE_KEY environment variables are required for
      this sample.
    `);
    }
    const auth = new GoogleAuth({
        credentials: {
            client_email: clientEmail,
            private_key: privateKey,
        },
        scopes: 'https://mail.google.com/',
    });
    const client = await auth.getClient();
    const projectId = await auth.getProjectId();
    const url = `https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/my-gsuite@domain.co.il/labels/label_id`;
    const res = await client.request({url});
    console.log(res.data);
}

main().catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the full error message.    Before you do anything you will need to set up [domain wide deligation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority)

Comment: thanks.
I've added the error.
domain wide delegation is set to true.

Comment: just to make it clear: domain wide delegation is true and still throws this error.

Comment: Hi, I posted an answer regarding this. Could you please clarify whether that solves your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

You are not impersonating any account in the domain. That's the point of domain-wide delegation: impersonating / acting on behalf of another account.

#### Solution:

You have to specify which account you want the Service Account to act on behalf of, by providing the property `clientOptions` when instantiating `GoogleAuth`:

```js
clientOptions: { subject: "my-gsuite@domain.co.il" }
```

So it would be like:

```js
    const auth = new GoogleAuth({
        credentials: {
            client_email: clientEmail,
            private_key: privateKey,
        },
        scopes: 'https://mail.google.com/',
        clientOptions: { subject: "my-gsuite@domain.co.il" }
    });
```

#### Reference:

- [GoogleAuthOptions](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/google-auth-library/latest/interfaces/GoogleAuthOptions.html)

Comment: Solved it! Thank you very much!

Comment: @mabruk You're welcome! Glad your issue was solved.